# Simple channel entries call, limit by category, not working

Tags: channel-entries

Simple as can be, my code, but I am getting all the entries, not just those in category 42.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="patient-services"   
disable="member_data|pagination" 
dynamic="no" sort="asc" orderby="title" category="42"}
    <li><a href="{url_title_path=patient-services}">
    {title}    
</a></li>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

**UPDATE** I stripped it down to this, but it's showing that every entry is in category 42, even though the CP shows otherwise. Maybe I hit a bug?

```
{exp:channel:entries id="18" dynamic="no" category="42"}
    <li><a href="{url_title_path=patient-services}">{title}</a>Category id
    is: {categories}{category_id}{/categories}</li>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Are you sure that that specific category_id is correct and exists?

– Wouter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct so I'd start troubleshooting with these three things:

1. Make sure your channel short name is correct (copy and paste it to be sure)
2. Make sure your category id is correct
3. <strike>Add dynamic="no" parameter to your channel:entries tag</strike>
4. **EDIT** Check your URL paths. A entries tag can seemingly misbehave if you have a misspelling in the template name. Let's say your template is /blog/entry but you are calling /blog/entryy by mistake. EE will not find the "entryy" template because it doesn't exist and so will try to load the index template in the blog template group instead. A good test would be to create a "test" template group and insert your code into that index template. If it works here, then something related to the URL may be in play.

Comment: yup, break it down to the basics and build it back up. Start with just channel name and dynamic="no" and work from there.

Comment: dynamic="no" is there in her code, other than that I completely agree with MediaGirl on the things to look at first, and with Steven that if those things turn out to not be right start by stripping the tag (and really the template) down to the minimum possible complexity and build from there until you get your issue back or have built back up to the solution you were trying to get to.  In the latter case, hot dang, you are good to go.  In the former, now you know a lot more about what is going wrong.

Comment: Turns out to be PEBMAK - Problem exists between monitor and keyboard!

Comment: I have that same problem!